# Difference Between Virtual Function and Conditional Execution on Machine Code Layer

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, virtual

I am trying to understand the concept of virtual functions. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function):

> **In short, a virtual function defines a target function to be executed,**
>   **but the target might not be known at compile time.**

My question is, how is this different from conditional execution?

```
void conditional_func(func_to_run) {
    switch(func_to_run) {
        case func1_tag: func1(); break;
        case func1_tag: func1(); break;
        ...
    }
}

int main() {
    read func_to_run
    conditional_func(func_to_run)
}
```

As you can see the ultimate target of the conditional_func is not known at runtime.

In C++, it seems that virtual function is defined as a facility to allow for "polymorphism". My definition of polymorphism: **A polymorphic class is a class with objects that can have different forms (morphology) as opposed to having a static form. That is, the objects can have different actions and properties based on their subclass.** (I'm avoiding mention of language specific concepts like pointers in my definition)

Therefore what is called a virtual function in C++ does not even have to be dependent on dynamic binding (runtime resolution of the target function), but can have a known target at compile time:

```
int main()
{
    Drived d;
    Base *bPtr = &d;
    bPtr->func();
}
```

In the above example, the compiler knows that the Base pointer is pointing at a Derived object, and therefore will know the target address for the version of func to run. Therefore my conclusion is that what Wikipedia refers to as a virtual function, is the same as C++ virtual functions that are for some reason dynamically bound:

```
int main()
{
    Drived1 d1;
    Drived2 d2;
    read val;
    if (val == 1) Base *bPtr = &d1;
    else Base *bPtr = &d2;
    bPtr->func();
}
```

As you can see this is also just conditional execution. So here are my questions:

1) If virtual function is defined as a function with unknown target at compile time, how is this different than conditional execution? Are they the same in assembly level but different at higher layers of abstraction?

2) If virtual function is defined as a facility to allow for polymorphism as defined above, then does it mean that again it is only a concept of higher level languages?

Comment: Why do you feel they have to be different? All the C++ language standard cares about is what happens when you call the function, not how it happens to be implemented.

Comment: Use an online compiler explorer (like https://godbolt.org/ ) and look at the generated code (remember to enable optimisation).  It's an implementation detail so you need to look at exact cases.

Comment: In the case where the actual type can be known the compiler is in fact allowed to make the call non-virtually. Remember that optimization is an as-if process, anything that can not be distinguished from executing the code directly as specified is allowed. It could even inline the virtual call or elide it entirely if enough information is available.

Comment: The reason for downvote? My question is what is the difference. If there is no difference then the answer would be there is no difference. This question implies that there is a difference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866703/using-virtual-functions-instead-of-if-statements-is-faster

Comment: _"...the compiler knows that the Base pointer is pointing at a Derived object..."_ : overly simplistic contrived example (just move the 2 lines into different translation units).  Given this the rest of the post falls apart.

Comment: @RichardCritten That example shows that in C++ terminology a function does not have to have an unknown target to be called a virtual function.

Comment: Also if we are using pointers to functions to different translation units then wouldn't any function pointer be "virtual" by your definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If virtual function is defined as a function with unknown target at compile time, how is this different than conditional execution? Are they the same in assembly level but different at higher layers of abstraction?

At the assembly/machine code level, virtual functions are typically implemented as class-specific tables of function pointers (known as Virtual Dispatch Tables or VDTs), with each object of those types having a pointer to its class's table.  The layout of these tables is consistent across base and derived classes such that given a pointer to any object in the heirarchy, the function pointer for any given virtual function is always at the same position in all the classes' VDTs.  This means the same machine code can take the object pointer and find the function to call.

A difference from the type of switch based code you illustrate in that all code with such switches would need to be manually updated and recompiled to support more types.  With function pointers, new code for new types can simply be linked to existing code that works via pointers, without the latter being changed or recompiled.

> 2) If virtual function is defined as a facility to allow for polymorphism as defined above, then does it mean that again it is only a concept of higher level languages?

Firstly, your attempt to define polymorphism is not consistent with C++ terminology.  You've got:

> A polymorphic class is a class with objects that can have different forms (morphology) as opposed to having a static form. That is, the objects can have different actions and properties based on their subclass.

It'd be closer to the truth in C++ to say that any given class has one form, and it's different classes in an inheritance heirarchy that may have different forms / actions / properties.

Onwards.  At the machine code level, you can - obviously given C++ has to output machine code - use function pointers and get the same runtime effect as virtual functions.

What virtual functions add is the convenience and reliability of having the compiler doing much of the work for you:

- create virtual-dispatch tables,
- ensuring consistent ordering of function pointers,
- giving objects an implicit pointers to these tables and initialising it reliably in the first non-abstract-base's constructor and updating it as construction bubbles down the class heirarchy to the actual object's runtime type, then reversing the value of the pointer as destructors kick in,
- checking that overrides have the same function signature as the virtual functions they override,
- optionally optimising away runtime dispatch when the called function can be deduced at compile time.

Such assurances and compiler-generated actions makes C++-style virtual functions and dispatch a higher level language feature than programmer-coordinated use of function pointers, let alone switches on runtime type.  That said, there's nothing in particular stopping someone adding such support to an assembly language.  That said, many languages that are on balance even higher level than C++ lack anything similar to virtual functions.  (At the extreme, a [5GL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth-generation_programming_language) may not even expose a notion of functions to the "programmer"/user).

Comment: Hi thank you for the great explanation. I think I was unclear in my question. My confusion is regarding the conceptual difference between virtual functions and conditional execution (if I use Wikipedia's definition of what a virtual function is) not the implementation differences.

Comment: @pooya13: your question concludes *"on Machine Code Layer"* - how is machine code not an implementation detail?  ;-)  Even with your comment above, I'm not sure what differences warrant being called "conceptual", but I'd say"high level" differences that virtual dispatch has over switching are listed above, e.g. the function signature checks and ability to pass new runtime types to code compiled to operate through the base class.  If that's not the kind of difference you're interested in, perhaps you could give some examples with other language features you know better?  Cheers